# Dual boot system (Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 7) doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

[image: picture of monitor showing an error]

I have been using the boot dual system since two years ago. But yesterday, after switching on the computer, the screen to select the OS didn't appear, only black screen. I have two partitions in one disk, sda and sdb. I have installed in `sda1` Windows 7 and in `sdb1` Ubuntu 16.04 with boot system. I enter into Ubuntu session using *live cd* and try several options: install `Boot-Repair` and `fsck` ... but the error is following. 
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Did you try `fsck -f`? Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201713/error-uncleared-pch-fifo-underrun-on-transcoder-a-during-boot-centos-7-on-tosh